# Updating metadata with using Couchbase eventing

Tags: couchbase

I cannot find anything related on the document. ***I just simply want to modify metadata (or extended attributes) and add new field for tracking if eventing OnUpdate function worked for source document before***. Couchbase version is 7.

Added picture, want to modify this area with eventing, not from any sdk, application etc.

What I tried(It won’t work):

```
function OnUpdate(doc, meta) {
var query = {"id":meta.id};
var result =  couchbase.get(mockProduct, query);
result_meta = result.meta
result_meta.xattrs.customfield = "some-custom-field"
couchbase.upsert(mockProduct, result_meta, result.doc)
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Couchbase eventing functions?

[image: Metadata]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Eventing Functions can not modify any attribute of a document's meta object (with the exception of an expiration date) or a document's xattrs.

If this is important please notify your sales team and ask that a CBSE be opened this will help prioritise your particular request as part of the future enhancement request backlog.

Best

Jon Strabala
Principal Product Manager - Server‌